# How to stream Video with WebRTC

Tags: ubuntu, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm working on WebRTC project from this link `https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#8`

And I'm able to send a photos from PC 1 to PC 2 in a same network. But I would like to be able to stream video between PC 1 and PC 2. Can someone please advice me how to configure a WebRTC `main.js` file for it?

I'm gonna paste here my `main.js` file whole, because I don't know which part is wrong, sorry for that...

```
'use strict';



/****************************************************************************

* Initial setup

****************************************************************************/



// var configuration = {

//   'iceServers': [{

//     'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'

//   }]

// };



var configuration = null;



//var roomURL = document.getElementById('url');

var video = document.querySelector('video');

var photo = document.getElementById('photo');

var photoContext = photo.getContext('2d');

var trail = document.getElementById('trail');

var snapBtn = document.getElementById('snap');

var sendBtn = document.getElementById('send');

var snapAndSendBtn = document.getElementById('snapAndSend');



var photoContextW;

var photoContextH;



// Attach event handlers

snapBtn.addEventListener('click', snapPhoto);

sendBtn.addEventListener('click', sendPhoto);

snapAndSendBtn.addEventListener('click', snapAndSend);



// Disable send buttons by default.

sendBtn.disabled = true;

snapAndSendBtn.disabled = true;



// Create a random room if not already present in the URL.

var isInitiator;

var room = window.location.hash.substring(1);

if (!room) {

  room = window.location.hash = randomToken();

}





/****************************************************************************

* Signaling server

****************************************************************************/



// Connect to the signaling server

var socket = io.connect();



socket.on('ipaddr', function(ipaddr) {

  console.log('Server IP address is: ' + ipaddr);

  // updateRoomURL(ipaddr);

});



socket.on('created', function(room, clientId) {

  console.log('Created room', room, '- my client ID is', clientId);

  isInitiator = true;

  grabWebCamVideo();

});



socket.on('joined', function(room, clientId) {

  console.log('This peer has joined room', room, 'with client ID', clientId);

  isInitiator = false;

  createPeerConnection(isInitiator, configuration);

  grabWebCamVideo();

});



socket.on('full', function(room) {

  alert('Room ' + room + ' is full. We will create a new room for you.');

  window.location.hash = '';

  window.location.reload();

});



socket.on('ready', function() {

  console.log('Socket is ready');

  createPeerConnection(isInitiator, configuration);

});



socket.on('log', function(array) {

  console.log.apply(console, array);

});



socket.on('message', function(message) {

  console.log('Client received message:', message);

  signalingMessageCallback(message);

});



// Joining a room.

socket.emit('create or join', room);



if (location.hostname.match(/vvv\.n-media\.co\.jp|192\.168\.71\.175/)) {

  socket.emit('ipaddr');

}



// Leaving rooms and disconnecting from peers.

socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {

  console.log(`Disconnected: ${reason}.`);

  sendBtn.disabled = true;

  snapAndSendBtn.disabled = true;

});



socket.on('bye', function(room) {

  console.log(`Peer leaving room ${room}.`);

  sendBtn.disabled = true;

  snapAndSendBtn.disabled = true;

  // If peer did not create the room, re-enter to be creator.

  if (!isInitiator) {

    window.location.reload();

  }

});



window.addEventListener('unload', function() {

  console.log(`Unloading window. Notifying peers in ${room}.`);

  socket.emit('bye', room);

});





/**

* Send message to signaling server

*/

function sendMessage(message) {

  console.log('Client sending message: ', message);

  socket.emit('message', message);

}



/**

* Updates URL on the page so that users can copy&paste it to their peers.

*/

 function updateRoomURL(ipaddr) {

   var url;

   if (!ipaddr) {

     url = location.href;

   } else {

     url = location.protocol + 'https://' + ipaddr + ':8383/#' + room;

   }

   roomURL.innerHTML = url;

 }



/****************************************************************************

* User media (webcam)

****************************************************************************/



function grabWebCamVideo() {

  console.log('Getting user media (video) ...');

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({

    audio: true,

    video: true

  })

  .then(gotStream)

  .catch(function(e) {

    alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);

  });

}



function gotStream(stream) {

  console.log('getUserMedia video stream URL:', stream);

  window.stream = stream; // stream available to console

  video.srcObject = stream;

  video.onloadedmetadata = function() {

    photo.width = photoContextW = video.videoWidth;

    photo.height = photoContextH = video.videoHeight;

    console.log('gotStream with width and height:', photoContextW, photoContextH);

  };

  show(snapBtn);

}



/****************************************************************************

* WebRTC peer connection and data channel

****************************************************************************/



var peerConn;

var dataChannel;



function signalingMessageCallback(message) {

  if (message.type === 'offer') {

    console.log('Got offer. Sending answer to peer.');

    peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message), function() {},

                                  logError);

    peerConn.createAnswer(onLocalSessionCreated, logError);



  } else if (message.type === 'answer') {

    console.log('Got answer.');

    peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message), function() {},

                                  logError);



  } else if (message.type === 'candidate') {

    peerConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate({

      candidate: message.candidate

    }));



  }

}



function createPeerConnection(isInitiator, config) {

  console.log('Creating Peer connection as initiator?', isInitiator, 'config:',

              config);

  peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(config);



// send any ice candidates to the other peer

peerConn.onicecandidate = function(event) {

  console.log('icecandidate event:', event);

  if (event.candidate) {

    sendMessage({

      type: 'candidate',

      label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,

      id: event.candidate.sdpMid,

      candidate: event.candidate.candidate

    });

  } else {

    console.log('End of candidates.');

  }

};



if (isInitiator) {

  console.log('Creating Data Channel');

  dataChannel = peerConn.createDataChannel('photos');

  onDataChannelCreated(dataChannel);



  console.log('Creating an offer');

  peerConn.createOffer(onLocalSessionCreated, logError);

} else {

  peerConn.ondatachannel = function(event) {

    console.log('ondatachannel:', event.channel);

    dataChannel = event.channel;

    onDataChannelCreated(dataChannel);

  };

}

}



function onLocalSessionCreated(desc) {

  console.log('local session created:', desc);

  peerConn.setLocalDescription(desc, function() {

    console.log('sending local desc:', peerConn.localDescription);

    sendMessage(peerConn.localDescription);

  }, logError);

}



function onDataChannelCreated(channel) {

  console.log('onDataChannelCreated:', channel);



  channel.onopen = function() {

    console.log('CHANNEL opened!!!');

    sendBtn.disabled = false;

    snapAndSendBtn.disabled = false;

  };



  channel.onclose = function () {

    console.log('Channel closed.');

    sendBtn.disabled = true;

    snapAndSendBtn.disabled = true;

  }



  channel.onmessage = (adapter.browserDetails.browser === 'firefox') ?

  receiveDataFirefoxFactory() : receiveDataChromeFactory();

}



function receiveDataChromeFactory() {

  var buf, count;



  return function onmessage(event) {

    if (typeof event.data === 'string') {

      buf = window.buf = new Uint8ClampedArray(parseInt(event.data));

      count = 0;

      console.log('Expecting a total of ' + buf.byteLength + ' bytes');

      return;

    }



    var data = new Uint8ClampedArray(event.data);

    buf.set(data, count);



    count += data.byteLength;

    console.log('count: ' + count);



    if (count === buf.byteLength) {

// we're done: all data chunks have been received

console.log('Done. Rendering photo.');

renderPhoto(buf);

}

};

}



function receiveDataFirefoxFactory() {

  var count, total, parts;



  return function onmessage(event) {

    if (typeof event.data === 'string') {

      total = parseInt(event.data);

      parts = [];

      count = 0;

      console.log('Expecting a total of ' + total + ' bytes');

      return;

    }



    parts.push(event.data);

    count += event.data.size;

    console.log('Got ' + event.data.size + ' byte(s), ' + (total - count) +

                ' to go.');



    if (count === total) {

      console.log('Assembling payload');

      var buf = new Uint8ClampedArray(total);

      var compose = function(i, pos) {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function() {

          buf.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(this.result), pos);

          if (i + 1 === parts.length) {

            console.log('Done. Rendering photo.');

            renderPhoto(buf);

          } else {

            compose(i + 1, pos + this.result.byteLength);

          }

        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(parts[i]);

      };

      compose(0, 0);

    }

  };

}





/****************************************************************************

* Aux functions, mostly UI-related

****************************************************************************/



function snapPhoto() {

  photoContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0, photo.width, photo.height);

  show(photo, sendBtn);

}



function sendPhoto() {

// Split data channel message in chunks of this byte length.

var CHUNK_LEN = 64000;

console.log('width and height ', photoContextW, photoContextH);

var img = photoContext.getImageData(0, 0, photoContextW, photoContextH),

len = img.data.byteLength,

n = len / CHUNK_LEN | 0;



console.log('Sending a total of ' + len + ' byte(s)');



if (!dataChannel) {

  logError('Connection has not been initiated. ' +

    'Get two peers in the same room first');

  return;

} else if (dataChannel.readyState === 'closed') {

  logError('Connection was lost. Peer closed the connection.');

  return;

}



dataChannel.send(len);



// split the photo and send in chunks of about 64KB

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

  var start = i * CHUNK_LEN,

  end = (i + 1) * CHUNK_LEN;

  console.log(start + ' - ' + (end - 1));

  dataChannel.send(img.data.subarray(start, end));

}



// send the reminder, if any

if (len % CHUNK_LEN) {

  console.log('last ' + len % CHUNK_LEN + ' byte(s)');

  dataChannel.send(img.data.subarray(n * CHUNK_LEN));

}

}



function snapAndSend() {

  snapPhoto();

  sendPhoto();

}



function renderPhoto(data) {

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  canvas.width = photoContextW;

  canvas.height = photoContextH;

  canvas.classList.add('incomingPhoto');

  // trail is the element holding the incoming images

  trail.insertBefore(canvas, trail.firstChild);



  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var img = context.createImageData(photoContextW, photoContextH);

  img.data.set(data);

  context.putImageData(img, 0, 0);

}



function show() {

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function(elem) {

    elem.style.display = null;

  });

}



function hide() {

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function(elem) {

    elem.style.display = 'none';

  });

}



function randomToken() {

  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 1e16).toString(16).substring(1);

}



function logError(err) {

  if (!err) return;

  if (typeof err === 'string') {

    console.warn(err);

  } else {

    console.warn(err.toString(), err);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
var configuration = {

   'iceServers': [

     {

    'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'

     },

    {
     //Your TURN Server Details, Eg: Below . Note You will have to setup coturn server

      'urls': 'turn:3.19.2.216:3478?transport=udp', //Your TURNServer IP and Port
      'username': 'sreeram',
      'credential': 'JaiSitaram'
    }

]

 };
```

and comment line:

```
//var configuration = null;
```

ALSO YOU WILL HAVE TO MAKE YOUR HOSTING HTTPS.